# SQL join on equivalent columns with different mapped values

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables that each have a CODE column, among lots of other data.  In Tables 1 and 2 (T1 and T2) CODE can have a value of A, B, C, or D.  In T3, CODE can have a value of C, D, or Z where T3.Z is equivalent to either A or B from T1 and T2.

What I'm trying to do in my Oracle stored procedure is

```
OPEN P_CURSOR FOR

SELECT *
  ( FROM TABLE1 T1
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON ( Stuff AND T2.CODE = T1.CODE ) )
    INNER JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON ( Stuff AND T3.CODE = T1.CODE )
  WHERE DATA = IN_PARAM_DATA;
```

This works as expected when T1.CODE = C or D.  However, this won't work when T1.CODE = A or B, because in that situation T3.CODE = Z.  Is there any way to account for this mapping in the query?

Comment: Don't use a cursor in sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement in your `JOIN`. I'm being lazy about following your actual criteria, but the idea would be something like:

```
ON CASE WHEN t3.CODE = 'Z' THEN 'A'
        ELSE t3.Code 
   END = T1.Code
```

Alternatively you could use multiple `JOIN` criteria with `OR`:

```
ON (T1.CODE IN ('A','B') AND T3.CODE = 'Z')
   OR T1.Code = T3.Code
```

If there's not some additional criteria present then making A/B equivalent to Z will generate multiple records per Z record.